# How to obtain 'x' via [object valueForKeyPath:@"frame.origin.x"]?

Tags: ios, key-value

The object is a UIView. I want to get x value of the object via `[object valueForKeyPath:@"frame.origin.x"]`, however i got following errors:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key origin.'

What's going on? And how to solve it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use that Code**

```
CGRect rect = [object valueForKeyPath:@"frame"];
CGFloat xCord = rect.origin.x;
```

**Or you can also get x through that**

```
CGFloat xCord = object.frame.origin.x;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is it possible the primitive type get its substructure or primitive type via valueForKeyPath? Such as `[rect valueForKeyPath:@"origin"]`, `[point valueForKeyPath:@"x"]` ,etc.